# trying to understand git revert, after git pull cannot find old commit or commit hash changed

Tags: git

I have a repo on a server, so I use `git push origin master` to push new updates and `git pull origin master` to get new updates.

today I had an old local build and I said I'll try the newest updates and if they break stuff I can simply just `git reset --hard <hash #>` right?  RIGHT!??

So I did this, in my old build dir

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

output: 377e72475de27b03540c86237q601f0e3fe96d761

ok cool I know my hash HEAD number.

so then I did this

```
git pull origin master
```

this pulled down my newest build, but of course soemthing is broken.  ok, cool I'll revert back.

```
git reset --hard 377e72475de27b03540c86237q601f0e3fe96d761
```

output:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '377e72475de27b03540c86237q601f0e3fe96d761': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

WTF?

Then, after using `git log` with keywords I recalled my commit decription and using grep I found that particular commit and the hashes are not the same!!?

```
# this is what I had prior to ALL this:
377e72475de27b03540c86237q601f0e3fe96d761
# this is the hash I found using `git log`:
377e72475de27b03540c86237601f0e3fe96d761
```

The "q" is missing from the original hash!  So what is going on here?  When I asked for the HEAD originally did it give me like a local HEAD hash?  Then I did pull from remote `origin master` and it changed the HEAD hash?  This doesn't make sense to me...

Also, prior to all this I did do `git status` in that old build dir and it was clean.

I hope this isn't too stupid to ask as I'm learning but this was just weird for me...

My last command I did revert back to by using the HEAD hash I found grepping git log remembering my comments, but wtf happened here man!!

```
git reset --hard 377e72475de27b03540c86237601f0e3fe96d761
```

output: HEAD is now at 377e724....

Comment: The id used for a commit never changes.  The id is calculated from the commit data and both are immutable.  The closest that can happen is a commit is rewritten by deliberate user action, but you'd notice a lot of other things had that happened.  To name a couple: the resulting commit ID wouldn't be similar to the old one; every commit ID after that one would also have changed.  Also, the value you're reporting as the "original" hash value isn't a git hash value.  Every git hash value is exactly 40 hex digits; your value is 41 characters, and one of them is a 'q' which is not a hex digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rev-parse` cannot have returned a `q` in the hash because it is not an hexadecimal digit.

If it truly returned that, I would be very suspicious of the hardware. Typically RAM is at fault, but in this case, since it is an added `q` rather than an overwritten byte, it means somehow the routine printing the hexadecimal number did one more iteration than needed, which is shocking.

Comment: the "q" was from the original hash.  So technically a `commit -AM ...` would have generated this.   So no rev-parse did not return a q.  This is a well kept macbook pro I doubt its hardware related.

Comment: I would also not bet on fawlty RAM or hardware, but `q` is still a rogue symbol here. I would rather bet on a mixup in the console : perhaps you hit the `q` key just after hitting enter, or for some reason some command sent a `q` to the console just at that point (did you by any chance have any command running in the background ? like an editor launched from the command line ?), or some buffer was filled and flushed and for some bad reason there was a `q` in it, or ...

Comment: You can re-run `git rev-parse 377e724` to confirm that the `q` is not there